# How to write CellForRowAtIndex for more than one uitableview on single uiview

Tags: ios4

I am trying to load three uitableview on my uiview
so i am getting the data on first uitableview but how can i write datasource code for ohter two as there is only one datasource method of uitableview i.e  CellForRowAtIndex .

If any one has solution on this then do write to me.

Thnks in Advance

Paggy

Answer (score 0):

I would use a data source and a delegate for each table view. Therefore you should have three data sources and three delegates.
Alternatively you could use the tag property of the tableViews.

Comment: Yeah but how that datasource method get invoked  or when it should it get invoke...